# .svc file gets downloading instead of running

Tags: .net, wcf

[image]

I have hosted my wcf service in iis and when we browse it's running but  when we click on the .svc it's getting downloaded instead of running.
Do i need to enable any settings in web.config in iis xml file or do I need to change any of the settings in inetmgr?

Comment: Have you tired to turning off Directory Browsing for the application from IIS? You will find this option in IIS if you click on the application (Features View) > then Disable Directory Browsing by double clicking on the feature (Option is available in Actions Pane )

Comment: It's related to many things , I think the wcf components isn't installed on IIS.

Comment: enable wcf service activation from the control panel